# Storing global configuration data in a pytest/xdist framework

Tags: python, pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist, pytest-selenium

I'm building a test framework using python + pytest + xdist + selenium grid. This framework needs to talk to a pre-existing custom logging system. As part of this logging process, I need to submit API calls to: set up each new test run, set up test cases within those test runs, and log strings and screenshots to those test cases.

The first step is to set up a new test run, and the API call for that returns (among other things) a Test Run ID. I need to keep this ID available for all test cases to read. I'd like to just stick it in a global variable somewhere, but running my tests with xdist causes the framework to lose track of the value.

I've tried:

- Using a "globals" class; it forgot the value when using xdist.
- Keeping a global variable inside my conftest.py file; same problem, the value gets dropped when using xdist. Also it seems wrong to import my conftest everywhere.
- Putting a "globals" class inside the conftest; same thing.

At this point, I'm considering writing it to a temp file, but that seems primitive, and I think I'm overlooking a better solution. What's the most correct, pytest-style way to store and access global data across multiple xdist threads?

Comment: you could use an external database

Answer (score 1):

Can you try config.cache E.g. -

```
request.config.cache.set('run_id', run_id)
```

[refer documention](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/cache.html#the-new-config-cache-object)

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth looking into [Proboscis](https://pythonhosted.org/proboscis/#writing-higher-level-tests), as it allows specific test dependencies and could be a possible solution.